# XMPP library for facebook chat

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat, xmpp

So facebook is opening its chat servers to us... great. I am new to XMPP, so what would be the best JS library to connect to their servers?

I googled for a tutorial article, but found nothing. Can someone direct me to one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Joschi pointed out strophe is a very good javascript library. But you need a [BOSH manager](http://metajack.im/2008/09/08/which-bosh-server-do-you-need/) to connect from javascript to XMPP. You could use a standalone manager like for example punjab.

If you can not run a BOSH manager then you could also connect to XMPP via flash without BOSH.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using strophe.js. For communicating directly with a different server and bypassing the same origin policy of javascript you could use strophe with flxhr plugin, which is a neat flash based workaround. So no connection manager setup (webserver proxy to  punjab and so on) is required on your server.

I also recommend the book "Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery". It comes with a whole lot of sample [javascript/html applications code](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470540710,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html).

Answer (score 5):

[strophe.js](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) is a powerful and widely used XMPP library for JavaScript.