# Is there a XMPP api for Dart?

Tags: xmpp, dart, facebook-chat

I am implementing facebook chat client using DART. As far as i figured out, i need to use XMPP protocol.

Is there a XMPP api for dart?

- If yes, can you lead me to source?
- If no, is there any good (for a complete stranger to protocol) source, so that i can implement one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything in Dart, especially since it's such a new language, but there's a [list of libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) on the XMPP page. Perhaps you can find one that you like?

This question points out some good libraries in Javascript: [XMPP library for facebook chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598900/xmpp-library-for-facebook-chat)

For protocol specifications, see [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/). Even if you find a good library to convert, you'll probably want to take a look at the specification anyway to really understand how it works.